# How to export a slide from Keynote with transparent background?

Tags: pdf, iwork-keynote

I'm using an Apple Keynote to do a bit of graphics and I'd like to export that to a PNG file with a transparent background.

Any idea on how to do this? I was thinking of exporting do .pdf (which is a vector format) and then somehow changing the PDF background to transparent, but I don't know whether this is possible and how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I finally did:

1. I exported the slides into .pdf
2. I opened the .pdf file in Adobe Illustrator
3. I removed the background in the Adobe Illustrator

Answer (score 1):

If you use the print dialog to export as PDF (instead of Keynote's built in export function) you can uncheck the box that says "Print backround fills" and then click "Save as PDF".

Comment: This is the better solution.

Comment: Problem with this is that backgrounds of shapes are removed too. (Keynote 6.2.2)